# Why do we need FOLLOW set in LL(1) grammar parser?

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

In generated parsing function we use an algorithm which looks on a peek of a tokens list and chooses rule (alternative) based on the current non-terminal *FIRST* set. If it contains an epsilon (rule is nullable), *FOLLOW* set is checked as well.

Consider following grammar [not LL(1)]:

```
B : A term
A : N1 | N2
N1 :
N2 :
```

During calculation of the *FOLLOW* set terminal `term` will be propagated from `A` to both `N1` and `N2`, so *FOLLOW* set won't help us decide.

On the other hand, if there is exactly one nullable alternative, we know for sure how to continue execution, even in case current token doesn't match against anything from the *FIRST* set (by choosing epsilon production).

If above statements are true, *FOLLOW* set is redundant. Is it needed only for error-handling?

Comment: I watched lecture, read book, implemented LL(1) parser generator, made usable C-subset parser with it and only then this question popped up. If you know an example where *FOLLOW* set is necessary, please, point it out to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is [not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207772/ll-1-parsers-is-the-follow-set-really-necessary).

I was asked precisely this question on the colloquium, and my answer that *FOLLOW* set is used

- to check that grammar is LL(1)
- to fail immediately when an error occurs, instead of dragging the ill-formatted token to some later production, where generated fail message may be unclear
- and for nothing else

was accepted

Answer (score 1):

While you can certainly find grammars for which FOLLOW is unnecessary (i.e., it doesn't play a role in the calculation of the parsing table), in general it **is** necessary.

For example, consider the grammar

```
S : A | C
A : B a
B : b | epsilon
C : D c
D : d | epsilon
```

You need to know that

```
 Follow(B) = {a}
 Follow(D) = {c}
```

to calculate

```
 First(A) = {b, a}
 First(C) = {d, c}
```

in order to make the correct choice at S.